# What do the positive and negative signs on the atomic orbitals diagram imply?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I was reading up on wave functions and electrons behaving like a wave when they are bound in an atom. In the orbital diagram, the + and - signs don't make any sense to me, and the reasoning that one side of the nucleus taken as positive displacement is probably wrong. Can someone explain it?

Comment: Not only charges have signs.

Comment: What do +ve and -ve mean in the first place? It seems to occur only in posts of India users and I have never seen an explanation of the symbolics. Does it mean positive and negative partial charge in multiples of the elementary charge? But I have seen it even out of charge context.

Comment: @Poutnik +ve and -ve are short hand for positive and negative and are used in any context where those words are used (not just chemistry - for example quite common in medicine for positive test results). Possibly more widely used in chemistry in India, but certainly not specific to there. I see it often here in the US.

Comment: @Andrew - Thanks. Interesting. Like being selfexpanding character macros.

Comment: @Poutnik The ve might mean "valence electron" I suppose. I was recently confused by this notation.

Comment: @BuckThorn So did I get very confused, thinking all the time about scientific notation I may not be familiar with. Seeing larger and larger scope of usage, I got more and more confused.

Comment: @Poutnik actually upon further thought the "v" probably represents a greek "$\nu$" meant to indicate a stoichiometric coefficient. Maybe there is a question on usage or notation worth posting in there.

Answer (score 3):

The sign on [atomic orbital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) diagram represents the sign of the respective [wave function,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function) (a solution of the [Schroedinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation)). It is analogical to sign of sin(x) function with positive and negative sections.

There are 2 major implications:

- For adjacent atoms, overlapping of orbital parts with the same/opposite sign causes constructive/destructive wave interference, known from classical physics. 2 electrons with the same quantum numbers in the same atom would lead to their wave function mutual cancellation and zero probability.
- Regions of the given orbital with the opposite signs are separated by 3D "node surfaces" with $|\Psi|^2=0$ and zero probability density of electron occurrence.

An orbital with the main quantum number n has n-1 of such node surfaces. E.g. the orbital 3s contains 2 inner spherical 3D surfaces with zero probability of the electron occurance, having 3 radial probability maxima.